# How to change attribute values such as "android:text" in android xml file with lxml

Tags: java, android, python, lxml

I would like to use lxml to change some attribute values of an android xml file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/version_label"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="version"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to change the "android:text" value, but

```
textViewTagNode.attrib['android:text'] = "new value"
```

couldn't work, neither

```
textViewTagNode.set('android:text', 'new value')
```

could work. All I get is "Invalid attribute name u'android:text' "

I know it's the namespace problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it may add the "python" tag because lxml is a python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is not `'android:text'` but `'{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}text'`

```
In [23]: s = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/version_label"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="version"/> </LinearLayout>'''

In [24]: tree = etree.XML(s)                                          


In [25]: c = tree.getchildren()[0]

In [26]: c.items()
Out[26]:  [('{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}id', '@+id/version_label'),  ('{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}layout_marginLeft', '5sp'),  ('{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}layout_width', 'fill_parent'),  ('{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}layout_height', 'wrap_content'),  ('{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}text', 'version')]
```

Comment: Thanks very much!^_^      I use `textViewTagNode.set('{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}text', 'new value')` and it does work!